# Drawing matrices on arrows of a short exact sequence (commuatative diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, diagrams, matrices

I want to draw a short exact sequence using the tikz-cd package. But I want the labels on some of the arrows to be matrices. I can´t seem to make it look good. The arrows are not approtiatly sized and my colum and row matrices do not look the same (clearly this is because I use two different commands, but I am not able to do row vectors with comma in a different way). The following picture shows what I want to archive. The minimal working example is what I tried.

[image: This is the lemma I am trying to reproduce, I would prefer to swap out the brackets to round bracktets]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Vector}{\lparen}{\rparen}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\Sigma_1 \colon \quad 0 \arrow{r} & M_1 
\arrow{r}{\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ f_1  \end{pmatrix}} &
E \arrow[column sep = large]{r}{\Vector{f_2,u_2}}
& F \arrow{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for somrthing like this?

[image]

The length of arrow was changed by passing an optional argument to the cell separation character `&[5ex]` and `smallmatrix` was used instead of `pmatrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\Sigma_1 \colon \quad 0 \arrow{r} & M_1 
\arrow{r}{\left[\begin{smallmatrix} u_1 \\ f_1  \end{smallmatrix}\right]} &
E \arrow[column sep = large]{r}{[f_2,u_2]}
&[5ex] F \arrow{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was using smallmatrix too...so I'm going to eliminate the one I was almost done with :-). My positive vote.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Another ưay is using library `positioning` with realtive coordinates, so we can easily control length of arrows. (using absolute coordinates is not convenient in this case). Also note the order of options: `node distance=5mm` must be before `right= of N2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\path node (M21) {$M_2\oplus N_1$}
node[left= of M21]  (M1)  {$M_1$}
node[node distance=5mm,left= of M1] (L) {$\Sigma_1 : 0$}
node[right= of M21] (N2)  {$N_2$}
node[node distance=5mm,right= of N2] (R) {$0$};

\draw[->] (L)--(M1);
\draw[->] (M1)--(M21) node[midway,above,scale=.8]
{$\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\f_1\end{bmatrix}$};
\draw[->] (M21)--(N2) node[midway,above,scale=.8]
{$\begin{bmatrix}f_2,u_2\end{bmatrix}$};
\draw[->] (N2)--(R);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need `tikz-cd` to begin with?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}

\newcommand{\mapname}[1]{%
  \left[\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}\right]%
}
\newcommand{\map}[1]{\xrightarrow{\mapname{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fmod}[1]{{\operatorname{mod-}}#1}

\begin{document}

Let
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\Sigma_1 &\colon &\quad& 0 \to M_1 \map{u_1 \\ f_1} M_2\oplus N_1 \map{f_2,u_2} N_2 \to 0 \\
\Sigma_2 &\colon &\quad& 0 \to M_2 \map{v_1 \\ f_2} M_3\oplus N_2 \map{f_3,v_2} N_3 \to 0
\end{alignat*}
be short exact sequences in $\fmod{A}$. Then the sequence
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma_3 \colon \quad 0 \to M_1 \map{v_1u_1 \\ f_1} M_3\oplus N_1 \map{f_3,-v_2u_2} N_3 \to 0
\end{equation*}
is exact. Moreover we have $\delta_{\Sigma_3}=\delta_{\Sigma_1}+\delta_{\Sigma_2}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]